# Can a relation hold all four properties?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I've come across a relation that satisfies all four of the relation properties: reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and transitive.

First of all, is this even possible?? and if so, is it a very specific kind of relation?

The following is the relation:

Let A = {−7, −5, −3, −1, 1, 3, 5, 7}

R ={(a,b)|a^3 =b^3}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If a relation is symmetric and antisymmetric, then the set only has one element (prove this!). I don't think your relation works for all four.

Comment: @SeanRoberson The relation $=$ (which is what the OP is asking us about) has all four properties.

Comment: Hint: $\,a^3=b^3 \iff a=b\,$ for real numbers.

Comment: @SeanRoberson A relation is symmetric and antisymmetric if and only if it is a subset of the equality relation.

Comment: @David a strict subset of the equality relationship would violate the Reflexive property.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Yes I know, I have already modified my comment.

Comment: @David so is this an equivalence relation?

Comment: @ShaunMoini Yes, because (I assume) you have already proved it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Comment: @David correct, but i have also proved that it is antisymmetric.

Comment: As to the question of if a relation can simultaneously be reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and transitive, see [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475354/can-a-relation-be-both-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-or-neither/1475381#1475381).

Comment: @ShaunMoini True but irrelevant.  An equivalence relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, and may or may not have other important properties besides.

Comment: @David then how would I be able to tell apart an equivalence relation vs. a partial order if all of the properties are satisfied?

Comment: @ShaunMoini Your example is **both** an equivalence relation and a partial order.  It is (essentially) the only possible example of this.

Comment: @ShaunMoini However equality is a very unusual example of a partial order and IMHO it's better to think of it as a "fluke" rather than a "typical" partial order.

Comment: @David THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality relationship (also called the identity relationship) has all four properties.

reflexive: $\forall x \in X : x = x$

symmetric: $\forall a,b \in X : a = b \iff b = a$

antisymmetric: $\forall a, b \in X: (a=b) \wedge (b=a) \implies a = b$

transitive: $\forall a, b, c \in X: (a=b) \wedge (b=c) \implies  a = c$