# Which defination is correct? (symmetric relation)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, relations

My [textbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uK4ITDfSHXk-JfBcKZsywkGA1fJ_yGUn/view?usp=drive_open)(2nd page, at very bottom) states the definition of symmetric relation as follows:

> A relation $R$ in a set $A$ is called  symmetric, if $\left(a_{1}, a_{2}\right) \in \mathrm{R}$ implies that $\left(a_{2}, a_{1}\right) \in \mathrm{R},$ **for all** $a_{1}, a_{2} \in \mathrm{A}$.

But [this](http://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/classes/w09/sem1/readings/ptw3.pdf) (from [this website](http://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/classes/w09/sem1/): Chapter 3) states defination of ......:

> Given a set $A$ and a binary relation $R$ in $A, R$ is symmetric if and only if for every ordered pair $\langle x, y\rangle$ in $R,$ the pair $\langle y, x\rangle$ is also in $R .$ **It is important to note that this definition does not require every ordered pair of $A \times A$ to be in $R .$** Rather for a relation $R$ to be symmetric it must always be the case that if an ordered pair is in $R,$ then the pair with the members reversed is also in $R$

Clearly both defination are contradicting   each other(if they are not then please explain me.)

Let me explain the question by a example.

Let we a set $Z$ such that:
$$
Z=\{1,2,3\}
$$
And also let a set $P$ be such that:
$$
P=\{(2,2)\}
$$

Now according to first defination $P$ is not a symmetric relation on $Z$, 'cause $(3,1)\not=P$.

But $P$ is  a symmetric relation on $Z$, according to second defination, because
$$
P=\{(2,2) (2,2)\}$$.
Which satisfies the condition of second defination.

So which one is correct?

Comment: How are they contrary to each other?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft because one says *for all* but other says *it is not necessary for every ordered pair*. Ain't they contrary? Please explain.

Comment: The first has some linguistic problems (but not to the extent of causing ambiguity) to write "If $P(x)$, then $Q(x)$ for all $x$". I would still prefer it if they wrote perhaps "For all $x$: If $P(x)$ then $Q(x)$". -- Apart from that, the second merely uses *every* instead of *all*

Comment: It might help to build intuition by looking at some of these small relations as graphs instead.  See my answer [to the question of if a relation can be both symmetric and antisymmetric at the same time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475354/can-a-relation-be-both-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-or-neither/1475381#1475381) where I talk about how to draw such a graph and what symmetry and antisymmetry means for such a graph in graph theoretic terms.  Reflexivity can also be easily defined in graph theoretic terms (*all vertices have a loop*) and transitivity as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are misled by the " for all" in the first definition, which you interpret as the requirement that the relation contains all the possible ordered pairs of $A\times A$ ( i.e. the cartesian product of set A by itself).
- The expression "for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$ " is simply a requirement regarding the ***origin*** of the ordered pairs : the ordered pairs must all come from $A\times A$. The expression "for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$ " is simply another way to recall that R is a relation ***on set A.***
- The definition says :

> for all pair $(a,b)_{\in A\times A} $ , ***IF $(a,b)$ is in R***, THEN  $(b,a)$ is also in R.

Comment: What is 'yto'? Is it a typo?

Comment: I cannot find  the typo you are referring to.

Comment: 'yto' was in second point of your answer. But now it's not there.

Comment: I have added a point. I think I have located precisely what bothers you? ( Point 2).

Comment: yes that was what bothering me. Thanks, Sir.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Each definition is equivalent to:

$\forall (a_1,a_2) \in A \times A : \lnot \left((a_1,a_2) \in R \land (a_2,a_1) \notin R\right)$

If we have $(a_1,a_2)$ with $(a_1,a_2) \notin R$ then $(a_1,a_2) \in R$ is false, so $(a_1,a_2) \in R \land (a_2,a_1) \notin R$ is also false, as required.