# Is this relation symmetric? $R={(1,1),(0,0)}\ $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

R={(1,1),(0,0)}

A relation is symmetric if xRy and yRx but can it be x=y?

Comment: Yes.  The relation is also transitive and if the relation is treated as being with domain $\{0,1\}$ is also reflexive and so an equivalence relation... the trivial equivalence relation where something is "equivalent" to another if and only if they are *equal* to eachother.

Comment: While not a direct duplicate, my answer to [Can a relation be both symmetric and antisymmetric or neither?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475354/can-a-relation-be-both-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-or-neither/1475381#1475381) where I describe the graphical interpretation of symmetry answers your question.

Comment: @JMoravitz its also antisymmetric too right? and it's transitive because it doesn't violate the definition of transitive relation?

Comment: Yes to both, and I refer you again to the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It symmetric.

If $\color{green}0R\color{red}0$ then $\color{red}0R\color{green}0$.

And if $\color{green}1R\color{red}1$ then $\color{red}1R\color{green}1$

And as those are the *only* two possible cases of $\color{green}x R\color{red}y$ possible, If we ever have $\color{green}x R\color{red}y$ it will always be the case we also have $\color{red}y R\color{green}x$.

---

Please let me know if you hare red/green colorblind.  If so consider this explanation:

If $\color{purple}{\large{\text{ZERO}}}R\color{orange}{\small{\text{zero}}}$ then $\color{orange}{\small{\text{zero}}}R\color{purple}{\large{\text{ZERO}}}$.

And if $\color{purple}{\large{\text{ONE}}}R\color{orange}{\small{\text{one}}}$ then $\color{orange}{\small{\text{one}}}R\color{purple}{\large{\text{ONE}}}$

And as those are the *only* two possible cases of $\color{purple}{\large{\text{X}}}R\color{orange}{\small{\text{y}}}$ possible, If we ever have $\color{purple}{\large{\text{X}}}R\color{orange}{\small{\text{y}}}$ it will always be the case we also have $\color{orange}{\small{\text{y}}}R\color{purple}{\large{\text{X}}}$.

Comment: If $ 0 R 0$ means nothing since we already know that $ 0 R 0$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I don't understand your comment.  If $0R0$ then $0R0$.  Nothing wrong with that tautology.

Answer (score 1):

A relation $ R $ defined at a set $ E $ is said to be symetric if, each time an element $ a $ is in relation with an element $ b$, then the element $ b $ is also in relation with $ a $.

$$(\forall a,b\in E)\; \Bigl(a\;R\; b\;\implies\;b\;R\;a\Bigr)$$

In your case, clearly, the relation $ R $ is symetric.

The relation is antisymetric if

$$(\forall a,b \in E)$$
$$\Bigl(a \;R\; b \;\wedge\;b\;R\;a\implies a=b\Bigr)$$

The negation is
$$(\exists a,b \in E)\ :$$
$$(\;a\;R\;b)\;\wedge\; (b\;R\;a)\;\wedge\;(a\ne b)$$

This is not the case. Your relation is also antisymetric.

It is transitive iff
$$(\forall a,b,c\in E)$$
$$(a\;R\;b)\wedge (b\;R\;c)\implies a\;R\;c$$

The negation is
$$(\exists a,b,c\in E)\;:$$
$$(a\;R\;b) \wedge (b\;R\;c)\;\wedge (a\;not\;R\;c)$$

this is not the case, so it is transitive.

Comment: Can it be transitive too?

Comment: @LightLamps Yes, it is transitive. I edited.

Comment: so 1Rb and bRc↦1Rc such that b,c=1?