# What is the difference between relations xRy in Z and Z+ such that xy=1?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I am trying to analyze the relation on both cases in integers and positive integers, and here are what I got so far:

Both are symmetric and transitive. Because xy = yx = 1 on both cases, and  if xy = 1, yz = 1, then xz = 1 also work on both cases, but I am not sure whether they're reflexive and anti-symmetric, please give me a hand, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As correctly noted by the other answer, the relations in question happen to be $\{(-1,-1),(1,1)\}$ and $\{(1,1)\}$ if it were taken over $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z^+$ respectively.

These relations are indeed transitive (*as any choice of $x,y,z$ (repetitions allowed) such that $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ result in $x\sim z$ as well*) and symmetric (*as any choice of $x,y$ such that $x\sim y$ results in $y\sim x$ as well*), easily verified since the only examples of times where we have $x\sim y$ or similar are when $x,y$ (*and $z$*) are all equal to $1$ or are all equal to $-1$.

The relations are both not reflexive.  This is because there exists at least one example of an element who is not related to itself.  For instance, $2$ is not related to itself since $2\times 2\neq 1$.

The relations are both not irreflexive.  To have been irreflexive would mean that *every* element is not related to itself, but this is not the case since $1$ *is* related to itself in both cases since $1\times 1=1$ is true.

The relations are both antisymmetric.  This is because every case of $x$ being related to $y$ we have that $y$ is not related to $x$ or that $y=x$.  It is indeed the case here since the only examples of times we have one thing related to another it was because they were both $1$ or were both $-1$.

I encourage you to check out my answer to [Can a relation be both symmetric and antisymmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475354/can-a-relation-be-both-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-or-neither/1475381#1475381) where I give graphical interpretations of symmetry and antisymmetry described using "single-sided arrows," "doublesided arrows," and "loops."  This relation is a quintessential example of one which is both symmetric and antisymmetric at the same time, the graph for it consisting only of loops.

Comment: +1 and You are of course right.I deleted my answer. One should not answer questions in a hurry.